# ¿Como buscar palabras de un registro contenidas en otro en python?

Tags: python, pandas, regex

Hola me gustaría saber cómo puedo buscar palabras o frases contenidas en otra en Python por ejemplo, tenemos lista de palabras o frases en la primera columna, quiero evaluar si esa palabra o frase está completa y contenida en la otra celda, si lo está que se marque true, de lo contrario false, no importa si tiene acentuación o mayúsculas.

Es decir, en la columna animal hay una lista de animales, quiero saber si esos animales pertenecen a los registros del campo Familia, en caso de no pertenecer, que marque False. Estaba pensando en usar un str.contains pero no sé que argumento debo poner.
Algo así

```
d["Familia"].str.contains("",regex=False)
```

No sé que argumento poner para que itere cada vez el nombre del animal buscado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Agrego esto que hice, ahora el problema es que no sé cómo guardar esto en un dataframe

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.array([["perro", "gato | leon"], ["gallina","zorro | gallina | vaca"], ["oso", "oso | conejo | caballo"],["coral",np.nan]]),
               columns=['Animal', 'Familia'])
df
```

|  | Animal | Familia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | perro | gato / león |
| 1 | gallina | zorro / gallina / vaca |
| 2 | oso | oso /conejo /caballo |
| 3 | coral |  |

Luego hago esto

```
animal_m=df["Animal"].unique()
fam=df["Familia"].unique()
     for i in range(len(animal_m)):
     a=animal_m[i]
     print(df["Familia"].str.contains(a,regex=False))
```

Esto itera varias veces y me devuelve esto

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: Familia, dtype: bool
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: Familia, dtype: bool
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: Familia, dtype: bool
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: Familia, dtype: bool
```

Es decir que si está funcionando, con perro, todos son falsos, en gallina el segundo es correcto y así sucesivamente, pero cómo paso esto al dataframe y que una los resultados.

Comment: Bienvenida Melissa Fonseca a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Creo que has cambiado la pregunta, podrías hacer una nueva en vez de cambiarla con ediciones. Así otras personas se ubican mejor.

Comment: También creo que has respondido a tu propia pregunta, lo correcto sería ponerla en una respuesta más abajo y no editando la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A continuación te presento una solución usando variables nombradas en español, tal y como en tu ejemplo. Sin embargo, te recomiendo escribir todo en inglés.

**Solución:**
Primero, antes del "for", crea una lista vacía en donde añadirás el resultado para cada fila:

```
esta=[]
```

Segundo, cambia tu "print" dentro del "for" por la siguiente línea de código:
esta.append(np.sum(df["Familia"].str.contains(a,regex=False)) >= 1)

En esta parte se aprovecha el hecho de que la suma de los resultados será mayor o igual a una sólamente si el nombre del animal está. Se usa el ">=1" y no el "=1" por por si llegan a haber familias con nombres de animales repetidos.

Tercero, añade la lista como nueva columna de tu "dataframe":

```
df["Esta"] = esta
print(df)
```

**Código completo**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame(np.array([ ["perro", "gato | leon"], 
                            ["gallina","zorro | gallina | vaca"], 
                            ["oso", "oso | conejo | caballo"],
                            ["coral",np.nan]]),
                            columns=['Animal', 'Familia'])


animal_m=df["Animal"].unique()
fam=df["Familia"].unique()
esta=[]
for i in range(len(animal_m)):
    a=animal_m[i]
    esta.append(np.sum(df["Familia"].str.contains(a,regex=False)) >= 1)

df["Esta"] = esta
print(df)
```

Yo uso "print(df)" al final ya que no estaba utilizando Jupyter Notebook en este caso sino VS Code. Al ejecutar lo anterior se obtiene:

[image]